# Amartya Sen's must-read works

Tags: reference-request

When I want to read an economist's papers I go to their google scholar page and sort by citations as the most cited ones are likely to be the ones they're known for

There isn't a google scholar page for Sen, could people here please recommend up to five of his must-read works? He's been mentioned in my courses (papers weren't mentioned, just his quotes) and I've been hearing about him since ages but now that I'm at a stage (econ undergrad final year) where I'm reading econ papers I'd like to read some of his writings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most cited papers(or books) of Sen are:

1. Development as Freedom (Anchor, 2000)
2. Poverty and Famines: An Essay on Entitlement and Deprivation (
   Population and Development Review,1982)
3. Commodities and Capabilities ( Canadian Journal of Economics,1987)
4. The Idea of Justice (Belknap Pr, 2011)
5. The Quality of life (Contemporary Sociology, 1993)

By the way, rather using Google Scholar to find papers, try with scinapse.io